# Is there any way to get an alarm notification on my iPhone if I get a certain email coming in?

Tags: iphone, gmail, alarm

I am looking to book a reservation for tickets and they send out emails when a ticket is available but usually it is at odd times and by the time I check my email and click on the link, someone else has already gotten the ticket.

I am trying to figure out a solution where if I get a certain email I get some sort of alarm notification (or a phone call or anything that will urgently get my attention) so I can go in and try to buy the tickets at that moment.

Is something like this possible?